# Can't install babel-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm getting an error when trying to run:

> `$babel-node ./server.js`
>
> The CLI has been moved into the package `babel-cli`.

```
$ npm install -g babel-cli
```

When I install it and run it again it asks again for it.
Anyone came across this situation? Can't seem to move forward.

>

```
 npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 start: `babel-node ./server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the relay-starter-kit@0.1.0 start script 'babel-node ./server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the relay-starter-kit package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     babel-node ./server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls relay-starter-kit
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/diogo/Projects/cf-ophite/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Babel Version 6 [split some packages](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/).

1. Did you try to **open a new terminal** window **after**
   `npm install -g babel-cli` ?
2. You can also install version 5 and work as before:
   `npm install -g babel@5`
3. If this happens after upgrading node, try `npm rebuild` in your project directory
4. Another solution is to **delete the node_modules** folder, and execute `npm install` again

Comment: even opening a new terminal window don't work. I can't downgrade to babel 5 because I had to update to fix some issues.

Comment: Deleting node_modules and running npm install again did the trick for me ! Thanks :)